# Binary converter alogrithim

Tags: python

Create a function called binary_converter. Inside the function, implement an algorithm to convert decimal numbers between 0 and 255 to their binary equivalents.

For any invalid input, return string Invalid input

Example: For number 5 return string 101

my code

```
import unittest

class BinaryConverterTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_conversion_one(self):
    result = binary_converter(0)
    self.assertEqual(result, '0', msg='Invalid conversion')

  def test_conversion_two(self):
    result = binary_converter(62)
    self.assertEqual(result, '111110', msg='Invalid conversion')

  def test_no_negative_numbers(self):
    result = binary_converter(-1)
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid input', msg='Input below 0 not allowed')

  def test_no_numbers_above_255(self):
    result = binary_converter(300)
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid input', msg='Input above 255 not allowed')
```

code has error pls i'm new to programming, home study actually

Edited
code

```
def binary_converter(n):
    if(n==0):
        return "0"
    elif(n>255):
        print("out of range")
        return ""
    else:
        ans=""
        while(n>0):
            temp=n%2
            ans=str(temp)+ans
            n=n/2
        return ans
```

Error report

THERE IS AN ERROR/BUG IN YOUR CODE

> Results:  {"finished": true, "success": [{"fullName":
>   "test_conversion_one", "passedSpecNumber": 1}, {"fullName":
>   "test_conversion_two", "passedSpecNumber": 2}], "passed": false,
>   "started": true, "failures": [{"failedSpecNumber": 1, "fullName":
>   "test_no_negative_numbers", "failedExpectations": [{"message":
>   "Failure in line 19, in test_no_negative_numbers\n
>   self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid input', msg='Input below 0 not
>   allowed')\nAssertionError: Input below 0 not allowed\n"}]},
>   {"failedSpecNumber": 2, "fullName": "test_no_numbers_above_255",
>   "failedExpectations": [{"message": "Failure in line 23, in
>   test_no_numbers_above_255\n    self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid
>   input', msg='Input above 255 not allowed')\nAssertionError: Input
>   above 255 not allowed\n"}]}], "specs": {"count": 4, "pendingCount": 0,
>   "time": "0.000112"}} out of range

Comment: I think you're going to need to show us the code for `binary_converter` -- As well as any errors that your code is actually producing ...

Comment: Great, you have unit tests! Now tell as which tests are failing and also add your implementation of the binary converter so this should be easy.

Comment: "Create... implement...". Nah. You can't command me to do stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
def binary_converter(n):
    if(n==0):
        return "0"
    elif(n>255):
        print("out of range")
        return ""
    else:
        ans=""
        while(n>0):
            temp=n%2
            ans=str(temp)+ans
            n=n/2
        return ans
```

Comment: see some tests are failing as expected. I didn't understand what's wrong in that.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Hint: always follow the tests given to solve such.

```
def binary_converter(n):
    if(n==0):
        return "0"
    elif(n<0):
        return "Invalid input"
    elif(n>255):
        return "Invalid input"
    else:
        ans=""
        while(n>0):
            temp=n%2
            ans=str(temp)+ans
            n=n/2
        return ans
```